# Delete Blanks, Null, Zeros in one go

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete rows where the data in column A is blank. This is a date field, if this is blank or null or 0 then the rest of the row is also null.

I can delete these one by one, however is there a simple way to have multiple conditions on an i loop. i.e. if cells(i,1).value = "null" or "-", or "0"

```
Sub delete_errors()

    Range("a1").Select

    For i = 1 To 10

        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "null" Then
        Rows(i).Delete
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Thanks

Scott

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub delete_errors()

    Dim dateCell
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    ReDim toDeleteRows(deletesCount) As Integer

    Dim toDeleteRowsSize As Integer
    toDeleteRowsSize = 0

    'Figuring out which rows to delete'
    For i = 1 To 30

        dateCell = Cells(i, 1).Value

        If dateCell = "" Or dateCell = 0 Or IsEmpty(dateCell) = True Then
            ReDim Preserve toDeleteRows(toDeleteRowsSize)
            toDeleteRows(toDeleteRowsSize) = i
            toDeleteRowsSize = toDeleteRowsSize + 1
        End If

    Next i

    'Deleting rows from bottom to top'
    For j = toDeleteRowsSize To 1 Step -1
        Rows(toDeleteRows(j - 1)).Delete
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Not my dv, but never iterate downwards deleting rows one by one.

Comment: Just in terms of it being slower?

Comment: @JvdV I edited my code and tried in my editor. It works perfectly. Copy and paste my code but don't forget to change number `10` inside `For` loop to the number of your rows.

Comment: That's not going to be reliable in any way. Someone downvoted for a reason! For test-sake add two consecutive empty cells in your data and run it again.

Comment: @JvdV I edited the code adding declaration for `Dim i` and removing few lines. It works on my PC

Comment: That's not the problem I told you about. Put data in `A1-A10`, then remove data from `A5-A6` and run your code again.

Comment: @JvdV that problem wasn't described in the question. If you need a full solution to a non specified problem then please submit a form to Microsoft or create a new question here on Stack Overflow. Thanks

Comment: That's the strangest of replies (i'm not OP). However, if you feel your answer deals with the issue at hand, then I'm in no place to tell you otherwise. Happy coding and a good day.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I appreciate the comments DVN-Anakin you technically answered the question as asked, which I appreciate but testing this jvdV is right. This only works if the fields being deleted are not sequential. As soon as they are the code needs to be run multiple times to work!

Comment: @Scottyp After you specified the problem I rewrote the procedure. Now it should work for sequential blank/null rows